# Is ServiceStack referring to WCF REST or WCF SOAP?

Tags: servicestack

So I was reading your docs in how you talk about WCF SOAP and how it binds you to methods.  But what about WCF REST?  You can add attributes that allow you to define Uri Templates so I guess I am trying to understand still the downsides of WCF with REST still...

Answer (score 1):

WCF REST is dead. It's an extremely cumbersome and in-flexible framework that mapped very poorly to REST-style services. Any new Greenfield .NET projects would be benefitted from using any of the more suitable [Web/REST Service Frameworks for .NET](http://www.asp.net/mvc/open-source).

I've previously discussed some of the [disadvantages of WCF in contrast with ServiceStack on InfoQ](http://www.infoq.com/articles/interview-servicestack).

Comment: no but can't you added the WebGet attribute and essentially create a service contract that is RESTful since that attribute contains a Uri element in it and method type pertaining to the Http Verb?